# Call Google's "match patterns" API?

Tags: google-chrome, url, google-chrome-extension, pattern-matching

The Chrome JavaScript API utilizes [match patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) in various places. In a Chrome extension, is there any way to manually call whatever functions Google uses to test whether a URL abides by a given match pattern? I have a bunch of URLs that I'd like to test.

Comment: @RobW Whoops, did not notice you closed the question. Now we have another implementation from scratch.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is not. However, it's not that hard to replicate using regular expressions.

Here's an implementation. It checks normal restrictions on match patterns, but does not check validity of host pattern / test URL host.

```js
function patternToRegExp(pattern){
  if(pattern == "<all_urls>") return /^(?:http|https|file|ftp):\/\/.*/;

  var split = /^(\*|http|https|file|ftp):\/\/(.*)$/.exec(pattern);
  if(!split) throw Error("Invalid schema in " + pattern);
  var schema = split[1];
  var fullpath = split[2];

  var split = /^([^\/]*)\/(.*)$/.exec(fullpath);
  if(!split) throw Error("No path specified in " + pattern);
  var host = split[1];
  var path = split[2];

  // File 
  if(schema == "file" && host != "")
    throw Error("Non-empty host for file schema in " + pattern);

  if(schema != "file" && host == "")
    throw Error("No host specified in " + pattern);  

  if(!(/^(\*|\*\.[^*]+|[^*]*)$/.exec(host)))
    throw Error("Illegal wildcard in host in " + pattern);

  var reString = "^";
  reString += (schema == "*") ? "https*" : schema;
  reString += ":\\/\\/";
  // Not overly concerned with intricacies
  //   of domain name restrictions and IDN
  //   as we're not testing domain validity
  reString += host.replace(/\*\.?/, "[^\\/]*");
  reString += "(:\\d+)?";
  reString += "\\/";
  reString += path.replace("*", ".*");
  reString += "$";

  return RegExp(reString);
}

// Usage example
// Precompile the expression for performance reasons
var re = patternToRegExp("*://*.example.com/*.css");
// Test against it
re.test("http://example.com/"); // false
re.test("https://example.com/css/example.css"); // true
re.test("http://www.example.com/test.css"); // true
```

Comment: One addition: the google implementation matches all ports (doesn't allow you to specify).  So if you need to deal with non-standard ports, you need to add `reString += "(:\\d+)?";` right after `reString += host.replace(/\*\.?/, "[^\\/]*");`

Comment: @Luke Go ahead and edit that in.